# Problem when trying to deploy Community Page on salesforce

Tags: visual-studio, salesforce, apex

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to deploy a community page to one sandbox. I pull the same thing from another sandbox.

These are my errors:
[image]
Here is my package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CommunityTemplateDefinition</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Dealer_Community</members>
        <name>CustomSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Dealer Community</members>
        <name>Network</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Dealer_Community1</members>
        <name>ExperienceBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

And this is the folder that generates error with loginAppPageId:

```
{
  "forgotPasswordRouteId" : null,
  "isAvailableToGuests" : false,
  "isFilteredComponentsView" : false,
  "isProgressiveRenderingEnabled" : true,
  "loginAppPageId" : null,
  "mainAppPageId" : "2fe3359b-d766-429e-9d67-ec8afe81cc47",
  "preferredDomain" : "none",
  "selfRegistrationRouteId" : null,
  "type" : "site"
}
```

Any ideea on this? Thanks!